# Dumbbell exercise

Tags: weightlifting, dumbbells

Someone told me that while I am practicing weight lifting using dumbbells, namely lifting the dumbbell from low waist region to say shoulder or chest level, if I move my shoulders while lifting it up, then it might lead to a shoulder sprain. Is what he says correct? If so, then how exactly am I to lift dumbbells without moving my shoulders even a tiny bit?

Comment: What specific exercise? There are some where you have to move your shoulders in order to do it.

Comment: The exercise to increase biceps and triceps, namely lifting the dumbbell from low waist region to say shoulder or chest level.

Comment: so you're talking about curls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are doing some sort of bicep curls. The safest way I can imagine would be to remove momentum. You can cheat yourself by standing with your back against a wall with your back and doing them in a cotrolled motion. If you are doing tricep extensions. .. I can suggest an additional exercise that is pretty effective (where you don't move the shoulders) if you want to try. 
It is called the Tate-Press: https://youtu.be/MJJwvJ9i7Mo

Hope that helps.